# Representing two-way street as graph network

Tags: algorithm, graph, graph-theory, graph-algorithm

Am doing some research on traffic flow and such , am having some troubles in representing a two way road on the network ... first though was to use directed graphs and this means I'll be having two directed edges between two nodes , I want to know if this is a good representation and if graph analysis(centrality,betweenness etc...) would apply to such graph

Comment: What you describe is a graph, so of course graph theory will apply. But note that graphs don't know about geometry; for instance, if the *angle between streets in an intersection* is important, you'll have to build it into the nodes yourself.

Answer (score 3):

Virtually all researchers concentrate on directed and undirected graphs, and not on the more general model - [mixed graph](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mixed_graph). This is since directed graph can theoretically represent mixed graphs by adding any bi-directed (or non-directed, depending on your semantics) relationship as two directed edges.

However, this attitude is far from optimal for some applications, where the mixed model is much more practical, such as [street networks](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Street_network) (e.g. supporting both one-way and two-way streets), [*M**3 networks](http://linqs.cs.umd.edu/basilic/web/Publications/2007/singh%3aiv07/singh2007IV.pdf) (e.g. multi-relational social networks), and many other use cases.

Nothing stops one for developing algorithms, metrics (e.g. centrality metrics), libraries, etc. that support mixed graphs directly. Nevertheless, mixed graphs never gained popularity. Take for example the most popular C++ graph libraries - The [Boost Graph Library](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/libs/graph/doc/index.html), [LEMON Graph Library](http://lemon.cs.elte.hu/trac/lemon/wiki/Documentation), [STINGER](http://www.stingergraph.com/), [MTGL](https://software.sandia.gov/trac/mtgl) and [igraph](http://igraph.sourceforge.net/) - none of these support mixed graphs natively. Even most graph databases don't support mixed graphs, but there are exceptions - [Sparsity DEX](http://www.sparsity-technologies.com/dex) for example.

In most cases, if you're looking for some metrics or algorithms - you'll have to implement from scratch - due to the lack of both theory and practical implementations. I hope we'll see some change in the near future.

Answer (score 2):

## Representation

Consider representing a road network with a directed graph in the following way.

- Road segments are nodes in your graph.

  - If a road segment is 2-way, there are 2 nodes for each direction.
  - If a road segment is 1-way, there is only 1 node.
- There is an edge from road segment A to road segment B if and only if:

  - The end of A is the start of B.
  - Proceeding from A to B makes sense physically.

This let's you model things such as intersections where a left turn is not allowed, or the inability at a T junction to make a U-turn.

## Example

Consider the following example.  Here there are 5 road segments shown and 1 intersection. Coming from below is a 1-way street, and only right turns are allowed at the end.  Drivers drive on the right side of the roadway.

The blue dots are the 5 nodes in the directed graph - one for each road segment.  The orange arrows are the 3 possible transitions from road segment to road segment that are permissible.

[image: Example]

Comment: I suppose you are talking about the "dual representation" ?

Comment: @fadytaher This doesn't have anything to do a graph dual. I am simply suggesting to directly model the road network this way.

Comment: please search "Can Betweenness Centrality Explain Traffic Flow?
Aisan Kazerani and Stephan Winter"

Comment: @fadytaher Why? You need to elaborate on what you don't understand or how this doesn't already answer the question.

Comment: I got what you said , it's just I need some "formal" papers with experiments/comparison with other representation to aid my research

Comment: @fadytaher Common graph-theoretic properties such as centrality and betweenness will absolutely make sense in this particular graph. For example, the betweenness of a node (road segment) will quantify how many shortest paths in the graph use that road segment.

Answer (score 1):

Road networks *can* be represented as a graph. One could see a map as a graph where the nodes are places which can be visited (towns, buildings, etc) and the edges are roads.

That being said, the effectiveness of your approach would depend on what type of information you include in your graph, for instance, an edge between nodes `N1` and `N2` would mean that there is a path between `N1` and `N2`, however, that information on its own does not provide any insight on how much heavy traffic does the particular street see.

To go round this problem, you could use weighted directed graphs, in which you could use the weights of the edges to determine the traffic on the roads and thus being able to yield a more complete analysis.

Comment: yes, an edge will represent a path between n1 and n2 , but in my situation I will be having  two paths in opposite direction , and weight will represent traffic

Comment: @fadytaher: If that would be the case, then you would also need a path between `N2` and `N1`, as you have stated in your question.